# Debugging RuntimeError: Object: Error in getting parameter as text from arcpy.GetParameterAsText()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, parameters, python-script-tool

I am trying to get this tool I've been writing for the past month operational. I think it should all work, but I'm getting caught up on the parameters of the code. Here is the start of the code that assigns the variables/parameters:

I commented out the report line, since it is for testing an idea(failed)

```
#importing arcpy, system, Tkinter as well as all of Tkinter's functionality
import arcpy, sys
from Tkinter import *
Convwks_fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)       #assigns the Feature Class to a variable based on user input for use in the tool
Convwks_lyr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)      #assigns the Feature Layer to a variable based on user input for use in the tool
irrdist = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
reportlocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

#report = reportlocation + "\"" + irrdist + "Report.txt"
report = r"\\agcifs01\GroupShares\agletirr\BenFerence\Python\Work\ConvwksAttributeValidationB\SMPReport.txt"

desc = arcpy.Describe(Convwks_fc)
arcpy.env.workspace = desc.path
```

Here is the error I receive when I attempt to run the code. I had gotten this same error on both of these variables: irrdist = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) & reportlocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4).

```
Executing: ValidateAttributesB \\agcifs01\GroupShares\agletirr\BenFerence\Python\Work\ConvwksAttributeValidationB\SMP2015TEST.mdb\Convwks Convwks SMP
Start Time: Mon Aug 24 14:42:46 2015
Running script ValidateAttributesB...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  "\\agcifs01\GroupShares\agletirr\BenFerence\Python\Work\ConvwksAttributeValidationB\Scripts\ConvwksAttributeValidationB.py", line 17, in <module>
irrdist = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 598, in GetParameterAsText
return gp.getParameterAsText(index)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 224, in getParameterAsText
self._gp.GetParameterAsText(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
RuntimeError: Object: Error in getting parameter as text

Failed to execute (ValidateAttributesB).
Failed at Mon Aug 24 14:42:46 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
```

I am passing a simple string to the irrdist variable and a folder location to the reportlocation variable, I don't understand why this error is being raised... Have any of you guys run into a problem like this? What was causing it?

Comment: Why is there no `GetParameterAsText(2)`? Can you provide a screenshot of where you assign the data types to the script parameters in the properties? Also, if you plan on using Tkinter within ArcMap, you're going to have a bad time: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/51876

Comment: Because I indexed them incorrectly, and just didn't even notice it until PolyGeo answered the question... I sit around pulling my hair out, and it's just the simplest fix possible...  Thanks for taking the time to address my question though man.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are configuring a Python script tool in a standard toolbox so I replaced your [python-toolbox](/questions/tagged/python-toolbox) tag (which is for Python toolboxes) with one for [python-script-tool](/questions/tagged/python-script-tool).

To set `irrdist` you are reading the 4th parameter (indexed as 3) but you have not shown us how that parameter has been configured on the tool dialog.

I suspect that you are not passing through what you think you are, and should check that.

If you are still stuck I think you should write a test tool that simply does:

```
import arcpy
irrdist = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
print irrdist
```

and configure just that one parameter on it.